# Can't use Breakpoints for debugging because debugger exit with code 1 right after i click debug

Tags: react-native, expo, vscode-debugger, expo-go

I am trying to learn react native for developing an android app. Using expo go, android studio and Visual Studio Code. While following an online course my instructor used breakpoints at some point and i wanted to do the same. But whenever i click debug, debugger won't stop at any breakpoints and immediately exit after compiling code. I expect it to wait for my commands like "step over, step in" etc. I don't have any experience with how to setup a debugger. Watched couple videos and read websites but i couldn't resolve my problem.

Also this error shows up at "Debug Console". I don't know if it is relative to this.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe .\node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js
(node:6456) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
warning:50
Uncaught SyntaxError C:\Users\fatih\expos\PatikaAppNews\node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js:1
import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1162:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at <anonymous> (node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47)
Process exited with code 1
```

I have tried typing "type": "module" inside launch.json file but it produced another errors.